# Laravel php artisan tinker throwing ErrorException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

If I run **`php artisan tinker`** on my console the output is:

```
[ErrorException]
in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given
```

And if I run **`php artisan tinker --verbose`** the output is:

```
Exception trace:
 () at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\ConfigPaths.php:161
 Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError() at n/a:n/a
 in_array() at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\ConfigPaths.php:161
 Psy\ConfigPaths::getDirNames() at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\ConfigPaths.php:35
 Psy\ConfigPaths::getConfigDirs() at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\ConfigPaths.php:89
 Psy\ConfigPaths::getConfigFiles() at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\Configuration.php:146
 Psy\Configuration->getConfigFile() at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\Configuration.php:117
 Psy\Configuration->init() at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\Configuration.php:98
 Psy\Configuration->__construct() at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\TinkerCommand.php:44
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\TinkerCommand->fire() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:503
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:150
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:256
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:136
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:838
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:189
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:120
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:107
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at C:\wamp\www\store\artisan:36
```

**Extra:**
My Laravel version is 5.1.24.
I've just installed [Zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)
Other than that, the app is almost blank

---

**EDIT:**

Here is the function guilty for the error inside ConfigPaths.php:

```
private static function getDirNames(array $baseDirs) {
    $dirs = array_map(function ($dir) {
        return strtr($dir, '\\', '/') . '/psysh';
    }, $baseDirs);

    // Add ~/.psysh
    if ($home = getenv('HOME')) {
        $dirs[] = strtr($home, '\\', '/') . '/.psysh';
    }

    // Add some Windows specific ones :)
    if (defined('PHP_WINDOWS_VERSION_MAJOR')) {
        if ($appData = getenv('APPDATA')) {
            // AppData gets preference
            array_unshift($dirs, strtr($appData, '\\', '/') . '/PsySH');
        }

        $dir = strtr(getenv('HOMEDRIVE') . '/' . getenv('HOMEPATH'), '\\', '/') . '/.psysh';
        if (!in_array($dirs, $dir)) {
            $dirs[] = $dir;
        }
    }

    return $dirs;
}
```

---

If someone has the same issue, here is how I solved it:

```
# add (array) before $dir
if (!in_array($dirs, (array)$dir)) {
    $dirs[] = $dir;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried `composer dump-autoload` or `php artisan optimize`?

Comment: Yehp, they run and finish without response, the issue remains :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the values on **C:\wamp\www\store\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\ConfigPaths.php** it seems like there is something wrong with those values because when the script calls in_array function doesn't get the correct values

Comment: I see where the error is happening now, but I don't know why. I added the function to the question

Comment: Check returned values for strtr or check dirs after the array unshift, remember $dirs should be an array

Comment: Forced the parameter of in_array to be an array and its working.

Comment: This was a regression in v0.6.0, fixed in v0.6.1. Just `composer update` :)

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me as well.

Perform `composer update` and update the package to psy/psysh (v0.6.1) fixed the problem.